# devenv.exe crash after debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

My Visual Studio 2015 (with update3) crashed when I tried to edit the source code after a debug stopped. (It also happens on C# WinForm, WPF, and Console Projects)
It was all right a month ago......

I got a System.AccessViolationException for the crash.
And I found something strange when debugging:

- Can't get any variables in my program, even in Immediate window
- But I still can get other info(like thread, stack ...)
- Diagnostic Tools isn't working
- After stop debug, the <programname>.vshost.exe still alive

I have already repaired Visual Studio, but the error still happened.

---

Operating System: Windows7 x64
System.AccessViolationException unhandled
Message: Type 'System.AccessViolationException' unhandled exception occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll

> At System.AccessViolationException thrown exception: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll'
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.EditAndContinue.VsENCRebuildableProjectImpl.OnReadOnlyDocumentEditAttempt (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentId documentId, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.SessionReadOnlyReason sessionReason, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.ProjectReadOnlyReason projectReason) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.EditAndContinue.VsENCRebuildableProjectImpl.OnEdit (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentId documentId) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.AbstractVsTextViewFilter  .Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsReadOnlyViewNotification.OnDisabledEditingCommand (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGuid, uint dwCmdId) unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.OnDisabledEditingCommand (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGuid, uint dwCmdId) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.Undo.UndoManagerCommandFilter.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn , System.IntPtr pvaOut) unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VerticalDetail.VerticalContentCommandFilter.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.Find.FindCommandFilter.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IntellisenseCommandFilter.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.BraceCompletionCommandFilter.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.AbstractOleCommandTarget.ExecuteVisualStudio2000.AnonymousMethod__0 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.EventHookup.EventHookupCommandHandler.ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers.AnonymousMethod__1 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.DocumentationComments.AbstractDocumentationCommentCommandHandler  .ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands .TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers.AnonymousMethod__1 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.IntelliSense.Completion.Controller.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.ICommandHandler  .ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands .TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CommandHandlers.AbstractCompletionCommandHandler.ExecuteCommandWorker  (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CommandHandlers.AbstractCompletionCommandHandler.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.ICommandHandler  .ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers.AnonymousMethod__1 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.IntelliSense.SignatureHelp.Controller.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.ICommandHandler  .ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands .TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CommandHandlers.SignatureHelpCommandHandler.ExecuteCommandWorker  (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CommandHandlers.SignatureHelpCommandHandler.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.ICommandHandler  .ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers.AnonymousMethod__1 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Formatting.FormatCommandHandler.ExecuteReturnOrTypeCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Formatting.FormatCommandHandler.ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers.AnonymousMethod__1 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.DocumentationComments.AbstractXmlTagCompletionCommandHandler.ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers.AnonymousMethod__1 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.RenameCommandHandler.HandlePossibleTypingCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler, System.Action  actionIfInsideActiveSpan) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.RenameCommandHandler.ExecuteCommand (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action nextHandler) Unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.ExecuteHandlers  (System.Collections.Generic.IList > commandHandlers, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands.TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action lastHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll! Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Commands.CommandHandlerService.Execute  (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentType contentType, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Commands. TypeCharCommandArgs args, System.Action lastHandler) unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.AbstractOleCommandTarget.ExecuteTypeCharacter (System.IntPtr pvaIn, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBuffer subjectBuffer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentType contentType, System.Action executeNextCommandTarget) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.AbstractOleCommandTarget.ExecuteVisualStudio2000 (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint commandId, uint executeInformation, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBuffer subjectBuffer , Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentType contentType) unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.AbstractOleCommandTarget.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint commandId, uint executeInformation, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.Exec (ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.SendCommand (System.Guid cmdGroup, uint cmdID, object inParam) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.TextInput (System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.DispatchTextInputEvents.AnonymousMethod__6_0 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.KeyProcessor p, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.Dispatch.AnonymousMethod__0 () Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint (object errorSource, System.Action call) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.Dispatch  (System.Action  action, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.MakeHandler.AnonymousMethod__0 (object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler (System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler (System.Delegate handler, object target) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler (object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl (object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl (System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent (System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea () Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput (System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.UnsafeCompleteComposition (System.Windows.Input.TextComposition composition) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.PostProcessInput (object sender, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs e) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers (System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea () Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput (System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.UnsafeStartComposition (System.Windows.Input.TextComposition composition) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.PostProcessInput (object sender, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs e) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers (System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea () Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput (System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput (System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessTextInputAction (System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage (object param) Unknown
>    WindowsBase.dll! System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Unknown
>    WindowsBase.dll! System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>    WindowsBase.dll! System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) Unknown
>    WindowsBase.dll! System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object arg) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk (ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) Unknown
>    PresentationCore.dll! System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage (ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) Unknown
>    WindowsBase.dll! System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage (ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) Unknown
>    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll! Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.PreTranslateInput (ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.MSG oleMsg, bool handled) Unknown

Comment: The Edit and Continue feature for your project is broken.  Falls in the "crap happens" category, it is a very convoluted feature.   Not much you can do beyond disabling E+C so this bug won't strike.  Or use source control to a previous version that won't crash.  Maybe run your code in 32-bit mode, E+C for x64 code is pretty new.  You'll need to call Microsoft Support if you can't live without it.

Comment: Since your Visual Studio is all right a month ago, please check the ActiveLog.xml under the path of %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0. This file will log all operations when you operate Visual Studio. If there doesn't have any error message in this file, I suggest you clear the Visual Studio caches under "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\" to confirm whether this issue cause by the Visual Studio caches or not.

Comment: I have cleared the cache, but it's no use. Though, disabling E+C function would avoid VS crashing, I still can't watch the local variables. Maybe the debugging feature is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Hans Passant's suggestion, at least, you have resolved the VS crashed issue after you disable "Edit and Continue" feature under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

In addition, if you couldn't watch the local variables, please check that whether it is related to the debugging options "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and "Use Native Compatibility Mode".

[image]

Comment: After checking the two options, the local variables works again!